# linux-boot-prober doesn't handle multiple initrd when parsing grub.cfg

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

My main machine is running KDE Neon, which is based on Ubuntu 22.04. Recently, I added an additional hard drive to my system onto which I have chosen to install Manjaro.

I want my KDE Neon installation to remain my main system so the corresponding drive is what I boot by default, which ensures that the GRUB installation added by KDE Neon will be my boot loader.

I executed `sudo update-grub` after having installed Manjaro in order to auto-detect this separate installation and to create a boot entry for it. This, as it turned out, came with its own difficulties but those have been resolved and now `update-grub` (or more specifically `os-prober` successfully identifies the additional Manjaro installation and a corresponding boot entry is created.

Only that when using that boot entry from GRUB, I get a Kernel panic. After having dug around a bit and comparing the auto-generated `grub.cfg` with the one that Manjaro generated for its GRUB installation (which works fine, if I use the BIOS to boot to its drive instead), I noticed that my Manjaro installation has the following in its `grub.cfg`

```
initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-6.1-x86_64.img
```

whereas the config generated on my KDE Neon for Manjaro only contains

```
initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img
```

Therefore, the the generated entry is missing the second initial ramdisk, which in turn (obviously) prevents the Manjaro kernel from finding some stuff and thus panicking.

I dug down into the internals of how `update-grub` or more specifically `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` works and tracked the issue down to the `linux-boot-probe` script or rather to the `/usr/lib/linux-boot-probes/mounted/40grub2` sub-script, which parses the `grub.cfg` file of the currently inspected boot partition (so in my case it directly parses Manjaro's `grub.cfg`) and then extracts the relevant information from that in order to (in a separate script) copy that into the to-be-generated `grub.cfg`. This particular script has logic in it to handle the `initrd` statement inside boot entries and it indeed parses the statement with the two ramdisk specifications from Manjaro's config. However, the code that processes this line looks like

```
        initrd)
            initrd="$(echo "$2" | sed 's/(.*)//')"
            # Initrd same.
            if [ "$partition" != "$bootpart" ]; then
                initrd="/boot$initrd"
            fi
        ;;
```

(it's part of a case statement) and the positional parameter used here are previously set to the individual components (space-separated) of the `initrd` line. That means that in my case `$1` is `initrd`, `$2` is the first ramdisk (`/boot/intel-ucode.img`) and $3 is the second one (`/boot/initramfs-6.1-x86_64.img`).

As can be clearly seen, the script implicitly assumes that there only ever exists a single ramdisk that needs to be processed and thus it only checks `$2`. However, in my case it would also have to process `$3`.

---

Now with all this context, my actual question would be: Is this a known bug? Has this already been fixed in more recent versions of `linux-boot-prober`? And who is currently maintaining these scripts. From a quick glance, it seems like these scripts are [part of Debian](https://sources.debian.org/src/os-prober/), but does that mean that the Debian maintainers are also the maintainers of this script or do they simply package the scripts and they are developed somewhere else (as with many other Debian packages)?

Note: I think I know how I can go about fixing this issue in my version of this script, but my question here really boils down to whom to contact to make sure this is also fixed upstream - and where upstream for this even is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here: After poking around in the Debian `os-prober` package, I found a bug report about this very issue: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=958218

I'll get in touch with the folks involved with that report.